# Do quasiparticles (phonons) bend spacetime or not?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, energy, gravity

I have read this:

> Recent research has shown that phonons and rotons may have a non-negligible mass and be affected by gravity just as standard particles are.[19] In particular, phonons are predicted to have a kind of negative mass and negative gravity.[20] This can be explained by how phonons are known to travel faster in denser materials. Because the part of a material pointing towards a gravitational source is closer to the object, it becomes denser on that end. From this, it is predicted that phonons would deflect away as it detects the difference in densities, exhibiting the qualities of a negative gravitational field.[21] Although the effect would be too small to measure, it is possible that future equipment could lead to successful results.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon

This is very interesting to me, because as far as I understand, everything that does have stress-energy does bend spacetime, even massless photons.

But I am confused by the statements on wiki, because, as I understand if phonons do have stress-energy, then they do bend spacetime just like anything else that we know of. Why would it work differently in the case of these quasiparticles?

Comment: Given the part of the article you quote, I don't understand where you get the idea that phonons don't "bend spacetime" from - on the contrary, it seems to say they *do* bend spacetime and contribute to the stress-energy tensor, just in a different way from normal particles.

Comment: In the answers to your question [Do photons bend spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/481557/do-photons-bend-spacetime-or-not?rq=1) an answer says, yes, they do. Phonons are nothing else as the structured excitation of a body with the energy from incoming structured radiation. Since the energy from the photons over goes to the phonons, they will have the same influence on spacetime as the photons.